# Theos build fails with : dpkg-deb: subprocess tar -cf returned error exit status 2

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, dpkg, theos

Theos is failing to build a package, yet it will 'make' it just fine. It returns the following with messages enabled:

```
dpkg-deb: building package `com.ethanarbuckle.alienblue++' in `./com.ethanarbuckle.alienblue++_0.0.1-19_iphoneos-arm.deb'.
dpkg-deb: ignoring 2 warnings about the control file(s)
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed to exec tar -cf: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: subprocess tar -cf returned error exit status 2
make: *** [internal-package] Error 2
```

I have not found a solution online, everyone says its an issue with tar, but tar is working fine. Does anyone know how to fix this?

It hasnt worked since I upgraded to osx 10.9, which Im sure is the cause of all of this :P

Answer (score 6):

That's because OSX 10.9 doesn't ship with gnutar anymore. You can run "tar --version" in Terminal to see if the it is bsdtar or gnutar.
One working solution for me is to reinstall MacPorts: Follow [the official guide](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) to uninstall MacPorts, and install again using [the installer](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.2.1-10.9-Mavericks.pkg). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. This is because dpkg won't build a package that has a identifier that isn't alphanumeric(ABC...123...) so it is rejecting the "++" in your package id. I suggest make a new tweak in the NIC and copy your "Tweak.xm" to the new tweak folder and give it an id something like com.ethanarbuckle.alienblueplusplus instead of com.ethanarbuckle.alienblue++. I had the same error and it took me about a month to figure it out. This change worked for me. Don't forget when you make a new tweak in the NIC to re add any framewoks you had imported. Your package name can still have the "++" in it, just not in the package id.

Don't use tar just run "make" or "make package"